# SRCNN with google colab [InvalidArgumentError]

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

```
learning_rate = 0.000000001

def init_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape, stddev=0.01))


with h5py.File('test_py.h5','r') as hf:
    hf_test_data = hf.get('test_input')
    test_data = np.array(hf_test_data)
    hf_test_label = hf.get('test_label')
    test_label = np.array(hf_test_label)

X = tf.Variable("float32", [None, 33, 33, 3])
Y = tf.Variable("float32", [None, 21, 21, 3])

W1 = init_weights([9, 9, 3, 64])       # 9x9x3 conv, 64 outputs
W2 = init_weights([1, 1, 64, 32])     # 1x1x64 conv, 32 outputs
W3 = init_weights([5, 5, 32, 3])      # 5x5x32 conv, 3 output

B1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64]), name="Bias1")
B2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([32]), name="Bias2")
B3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3]), name="Bias3")

L1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(X, W1,                       # l1 shape=(?, 25, 25, 64)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID') + B1)
L2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(L1, W2,                     # l2 shape=(?, 25, 25, 32)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID') + B2)

hypothesis = tf.nn.conv2d(L2, W3,                     # l3 shape=(?, 21, 21, 3)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID') + B3
```

---

InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'T' of string is not in the list of allowed values: half, bfloat16, float, double, int32
; NodeDef: {{node Conv2D}}; Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID", "EXPLICIT"]; attr=explicit_paddings:list(int),default=[]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]; attr=dilations:list(int),default=[1, 1, 1, 1]> [Op:Conv2D] name:

What should I do?
Should I change floa32 to another argument?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).